# Counting the frequency of words in a sorted list

Tags: java, loops, exception, frequency

```
public static void frequencyFinder() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    String foldername = ".../Meta_Oct/separate";
    File folder = new File(foldername);
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();


    String line;
    for (int x = 0; x < listOfFiles.length; x++) {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(listOfFiles[x]));
        String filename = listOfFiles[x].getName();
        String language = filename.split("@")[0];
        String target = filename.split("@")[1];
        String source = filename.split("@")[2];
        int frequency = 0;

        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            lemma_match = line.split(";")[3];
            frequency = 1;
            while((in.readLine().split(";")[3]).equals(lemma_match)){                 
                frequency++;
                line = in.readLine();                    
            }

            System.out.println(target + ":" + source +":"+lemma_match + ":" + frequency);
            frequency = 0;                
            lemma_match = null;
        }


    }
}
```

The frequency of the words in the last column has to be calculated. The problem is that the while loop skips some of the lines and it ends up in `NullPointerException`s and not all frequencies are calculated until that point either. I have attached the stack trace below, as well as the sample file.

```
EN;GOVERNMENT;DISEASE;bristle at 
EN;GOVERNMENT;DISEASE;contract 
EN;GOVERNMENT;DISEASE;detect in 
EN;GOVERNMENT;DISEASE;detect in 
EN;GOVERNMENT;DISEASE;immunize against 
EN;GOVERNMENT;DISEASE;inherit from 
EN;GOVERNMENT;DISEASE;spread 
EN;GOVERNMENT;DISEASE;spread 
EN;GOVERNMENT;DISEASE;spread 
EN;GOVERNMENT;DISEASE;stave off 
EN;GOVERNMENT;DISEASE;stave off 
EN;GOVERNMENT;DISEASE;transmit 
EN;GOVERNMENT;DISEASE;treat 
EN;GOVERNMENT;DISEASE;treat 
EN;GOVERNMENT;DISEASE;treat as 
EN;GOVERNMENT;DISEASE;treat by 
EN;GOVERNMENT;DISEASE;ward off
```

STACK TRACE:

```
GOVERNMENT:DISEASE:bristle at :1
GOVERNMENT:DISEASE:detect in :2
GOVERNMENT:DISEASE:spread :2
GOVERNMENT:DISEASE:stave off :1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
GOVERNMENT:DISEASE:treat :2
    at javaapplication6.FrequencyFinder.frequencyFinder(FrequencyFinder.java:53)
    at javaapplication6.FrequencyFinder.main(FrequencyFinder.java:26)
Java Result: 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code has problems :

```
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) { // here you read a line
        lemma_match = line.split(";")[3];
        frequency = 1;
        while((in.readLine().split(";")[3]).equals(lemma_match)){ // here you read
                                                                  // another line
            frequency++;
            line = in.readLine(); // here you read another line                   
        }
```

Since you read a new line in 3 places within this code, you don't increment the frequency for all of these reads. For example, in each iteration of the inner loop you are reading two lines, but only increment `frequency` once. Even if you fix the inner loop, you would still miss some lines when the inner while loop ends and the outer while loop reads a new line.

In addition, the inner while loop will give you `NullPointerException`, since you don't check that `in.readLine() != null` before trying to `split` it.

Now lets see how we can do this with a single loop :

```
    String lemma_match = "";
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        String new_lemma_match = line.split(";")[3];
        if (!lemma_match.equals(new_lemma_match)) { // start count for a new lemma
            if (!lemma_match.equals("")) {
                System.out.println(target + ":" + source +":"+lemma_match + ":" + frequency);
            }
            lemma_match=new_lemma_match;
            frequency = 1; // initialize frequency for new lemma
        } else {
            frequency++; // increase frequency for current lemma
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

keep on adding the entries in hashmap. for each unique entry(key) increment the value . finally you will get your result.